# Creating new page from webform entry

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm trying to create a webform that generates a new page filled with that submission data. So certain users can add/edit new pages easily.
Is there a certain webform setting I'm missing for this? I've looked around and have only managed to get the data to display on a single view in a table.
Thanks!

Comment: Check out https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_content_creator

Comment: ok yes these are helpful. Thank you!